# What is the difference between an if CI_COMMIT_TAG rule and only:tags?

Tags: gitlab-ci

The Gitlab CI documentation recommends a rule like

```yaml
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

to run jobs exclusively on tags. See for example https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/index.html#use-a-generic-package-for-attaching-binaries. What is the difference with

```yaml
only:
  - tags
```

In my opinion these should be equivalent and my tests point in that direction as well. However, I'm not sure and can't find any explanation in the documentation why the `only:tags` method is not used in this specific example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functionally the are the same but the preferred keyword is now `rules`.

From the [Keyword Reference page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except):

```
only and except are not being actively developed. rules is the preferred keyword to control when to add jobs to pipelines.
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I skipped that info box when reading the reference.